# How to write unit test case for Global Exception handler using UseExceptionHandler middleware

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core, nunit, xunit.net

I've created global exception handler class as below

```
public static void UseGlobalExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder app, ILogger logger)
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler(
            options => options.Run(
                async context =>
                {
                    var env = context.RequestServices.GetService<IHostingEnvironment>();
                    var general = context.RequestServices.GetService<General>();
                    var exHandlerFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    var exception = exHandlerFeature.Error;
                    LogException(logger, exception);
                    JObject response = CreateResponseMessage(exception,env,general);
                    if (!context.Response.HasStarted)
                    {
                        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", new StringValues("true"));
                        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new StringValues("*"));
                        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(json);
                    }         
                }
                )
            );
    }
```

I'm new to writing the unit test cases. I want to know how to mock the exception handling middleware with the mentioned parameters/variables in the above mentioned code and write the test case for the same.

Comment: extract the handler delegate out into a separate method and test that

Comment: @Nkosi, Could you please provide some sample code to do that?

Comment: Have you managed to write test cases for this? I am looking for the same thing.